# quasi-SVM for a custom dataset(binary classifier)

Tags: tensorflow, svm, tf.keras

I used the code for Quasi-SVM and had error.

```
model = keras.Sequential(
[
    keras.Input(shape=(50176,)),
    keras.layers.experimental.RandomFourierFeatures(
    output_dim=4096, scale=10.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=10),
]
```

)

Error:
Input 0 of layer "random_fourier_features" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)

Comment: Please share the input data shape or the minimal reproducible code to replicate the error and fix the issue.